# Layout disappear When I Run App On My Phone

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Layout disappear When I Run App On My Phone is there any solution to run application in any orientation with same layout.

Comment: Please provide more information

Comment: If you don't declare multiple layout for each orientation, it will use the only one layout. Please include your manifest, screenshot of layout folder, and your code